# Determine whether in two rows one is a header or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, nlp

I am trying to do a task that is quite simple to do by a human: detect whether the first of two rows is a header row. Here's an example of sample inputs:

Example1: yes

```
name,age
bob,12
```

Example2: yes

```
first,last
bob,jones
```

Example3: no

```
1,2
8,hi
```

Example4: no

```
bob,jones
tom,smith
```

I'm a bit lost of where to begin to make an educated guess here. It doesn't have to be perfect (80% would be good), but what might be a good short-hand algorithm to determine the above? Some things I was thinking of:

```
# header is usually always strings (wrong in case 4)
for val in header:

    is val.replace(',','').replace('.','').replace('-','').isdigit():
        header = False
    else:
        header = True
```

Comment: Would it be sufficient to test if the first character of every value is a letter? I'm thinking `is_header = all(str(v)[0].isalpha() for v in header)`

Comment: @JoeHalliwell that's a good idea, yes. Do you think there are other good criteria to test whether something is a header row as well?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to have a preset list of keywords to search for in your row; such as `['name', 'age', 'first', 'last']`. Of course this should be in addition to your digit check.
If you have one or more matches then call it a header.

Comment: thanks, though I'm looking for a more general approach -- as in, I don't know the header names before parsing the file.

Comment: @David542 My thought is that we, as humans, already have that list or terms. We know that certain words (name, age...) represent categories and not individual items within the category. When you look at your table and read the elements you right away determine the meaning of each item and place it in the correct category. This is purpose of the preset list I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that words are common nouns in your data header. You can use some NLP framework such as [TextBlob](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob) to do POS(Part of Speech) job for recognizing a word if it is a noun or a people's name.